# Rate a YouTube video using API v3

Tags: ios, youtube-data-api

How do I rate (dislike/like) a video on YouTube by some other person in iOS using the YouTube API v3?

I didn't understand how to do it from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate).

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer,

```
-(void) rateVideo
{
    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosRateWithIdentifier:videoId rating:@"dislike"]; // rating can be anything "like" or "dislike" etc

    [_youTubeService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeVideoRating *rate, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"err : %@",error);
    }];
}
```